# How to get access to the Internet from a Go program running on Android?

Tags: android, go

My program can't access to internet when put in android terminal, but in linux works fine.
(wget (busybox) works fine with internet in android terminal)

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func Url(url string)(string, io.ReadCloser, http.Header, error){
    var c = http.Client{}
    inf, err := c.Get(url)
    if err == nil {
        data,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(inf.Body)
        return string(data), inf.Body, inf.Header, err
    }
    return "", nil, nil, err
}

func main() {
    print("test internet... ")
    c,_,_,err := Url("http://ifconfig.me/ip")
    if err == nil {
        println("\n ip:", c)
    }else{
        println("error")
    }
}
```

compiling with:

```
go build main.go    # linux
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build $(bin).go    # android
```

Comment: How are you running this? What error do you get?  Are you sure the code is running at all?

Comment: with Status of http.Response in linux "`200 OK`", in android (xperia s) print var err: "`Get http://ifconfig.me/ip: error reading DNS config: open /etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory`", the file /etc/resolv.conf no exists, the problem is how are been compiled?

Comment: Don't forget, you can use the `edit` button to add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not have full support for Go yet. If at some point in the future they add a Go sdk this will be easier. But for right now unless you feel like modifying Go's source yourself or writing your own set of libraries to handle Androids different environment this is going to be difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Android does not have an /etc/resolv.conf

Somewhere in your code, or more likely one of those libraries you import, you are assuming a traditional linux userspace, which is not the case on Android.

maybe the "GOOS=linux" is the source of the mistake.

Comment: maybe, the only thing I found is this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/t1qRnZtYP1w/WMTu5ByftLQJ) but I don't know how...

Comment: I believe that you'll find it at /system/etc/resolv.conf under android.  Not sure how you tell Go that - it is the kind of thing that is burnt into the C runtime usually.